# Making Login Form show on every page?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, controllers

Hi I'm trying to get my login form to show on every page of my site, however I'm struggling doing this as I keep getting "Undefined username and password" errors on other pages that are not using the controller that has the method "login()" in.

I've use a master controller (MY_Controller) which extends my other controllers.

**MY_Controller File:**

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    public $template;
    public $template2;

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->template = 'templates/default'; // Set default layout
        $this->template2 = 'templates/other';
    }
}
```

**Users Controller - Login Part:**

```
class Users extends MY_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('form'); // Load the form helper to allow the use of forms.
    }

    /* Other register function is here*/

    public function login(){
        $data['page'] = 'login';

        $data['username'] = array(
            'name' => 'username',
            'placeholder' => 'Enter username'
        );
        $data['password'] = array(
            'name' => 'password',
            'type' => 'password',
            'placeholder' => 'Enter password'
        );

        $this->load->view($this->template, $data);
  }
```

**Part of Default Template File:**

```
    <div id="container">

        <div id="contentArea">
            <h2 class="pageTitle"><?php echo isset($title) && strlen($title) > 1 ? $title : 'Unknown Title'; ?></h2>
            <?php $this->load->view($page); ?>
        </div>
        <div id="aside">
            <h3>Login</h3>
            <?php $this->load->view('login'); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

If anyone has any ideas as to how I can solve this issue please let me know, thanks in advance.

Comment: "I'm trying to get my login form to show on every page of my site". You wan to put a div of login on every page or you want to force the user to login to see the page if he isn't authenticated?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to solve this matter. Personally I make a custom helper with is auto loaded and run most of my views through there.

So instead of `$this->load->view($this->template, $data);`

I run `load_index('login', $data)`

**helpers/general_helper.php**

```
function load_index($content, $data = array()) {

    $CI =& get_instance();

    $data += array('page'     => $content,
                   'username' => array('username' => 'username',
                                       'placeholder' => 'Enter username'),
                   'password' => array('name' => 'password',
                                       'type' => 'password',
                                       'placeholder' => 'Enter password'));

    $CI->load->view($CI->template, $data);

}
```

CodeIgniter gives you thousands of alternatives. Think it through and pick the one you prefer.